# ArgumentOutOfRangeException error

Tags: vb.net, exception, visual-studio-2013, outofrangeexception

I am trying to create an application that handles patient files in a hospital. 
It gives me an error and tells me **PatientView = PatientCollection(counter)** - ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled. What does this mean and how do I fix this?

```
Public Class SelectPatient

Private Sub SelectPatient_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.Text = "Select Patient"

    Dim counter As Integer = 0

    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    For counter = 0 To PatientCollection.Count
        Dim PatientView As New PatientObject4
        PatientView = PatientCollection(counter)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(PatientView.LastName & "," & PatientView.Firstname)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    CollectionIndexValue = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex

    Globals.NewPatientData()



End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks very much for your time. Much appreciated

Comment: For counter = 0 To PatientCollection.Count-1

Comment: Why did you erase your question? You should either leave it as is since it was apparently a perfectly relevant question, or delete it (though I would not would recommend this for the aforementioned reason).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in NET Framework start at index zero and end at Count - 1.

In your loop

```
For counter = 0 To PatientCollection.Count
```

you stop at Count, so the last valued assumed by `counter` is not valid.
You need to change that loop to

```
For counter = 0 To PatientCollection.Count - 1
```

The property Count for an array represents the number of items contained in the array. So, if the first index is zero, the last one should be Count - 1